# Request from load balancer to API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-elb

I have a web application which is in an Amazon EC2 instance, and a domain pointing to a load balancer. The load balancer is forwarding requests to the instance. This is working fine.

Now we have new requirement to develop an API. We developed through API Gateway. But this API also should be in same domain, for example `https://domain/API` should hit API Gateway.

Is this possible to configure in load balancer to forward requests to API Gateway? Or any other approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think u want a message queue for ur use case. This way u can alert messages on current event processing in a frontend manner for your gateway or any other client connection with a scalable approach.

I’m sure others will correct me if I am wrong, but a load balancer is to control traffic to servers not a web api portal. An http load balancer is described [here](https://medium.com/martinomburajr/distributed-computing-tcp-vs-http-s-load-balancing-7b3e9efc6167): from my basic knowledge of load balancer and message queues I think I’m right here.